# Regex Retrieve all text before string until space

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the coefficient of "a" in a quadratic equation (ax^2 + bx + c).
However, the length of the coefficient can vary.
For instance, here are some of the intended outcomes:

```
input: 5x^2 + 3x + 4
output: 5
```

```
input: 12x^2 + 2x - 6
output: 12
```

The number could also be in the middle of the equation.

```
input: 2x - 3x^2 + 4
output: 3
```

How would I get the whole text before "x^2" until their is a white space?

I have tried using the split() function:

```
a = equation.split("x^2")
a = a[0]
```

but this would not work in the third example

Comment: Please tell us what you tried

Comment: Why not to use `split`?

Comment: @rootkonda I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are

```
[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?(?=x\^)
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/lyzXfL/1/)

Be aware that this regex will only match simple cases, for example, it will not match 2E3.

Comment: It works for the most part, but it does not include the + or - in the result. For example: input: 2x - 3x^2 output: 3

Comment: You may add an optionnal space between the operator and the number : 
```[-+]?\s?\d+(\.\d+)?(?=x\^)```

Answer (score 0):

Tip: use [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/r/gybEW4/1) to test your pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'([\+\-\d.]*)x\^2')
tests = [
    '5x^2 + 3x + 4',
    '12x^2 + 2x - 6',
    '2x - 3x^2 + 4',
    'x^2 - 2x + 1',
    '-x^2 + 6x - 9'
]

for t in tests:
    m = pattern.search(t)
    text = m.group(1)

    if text == '':
        coeff = 1
    elif text == '-':
        coeff = -1
    else:
        coeff = float(text)

    print(coeff)
```

Prints:

```
5.0
12.0
3.0
1
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that using `split` is an option too from the question. So you want to get the whole text before the numbers with the `^` operator.
This will only work for these three examples:

```
x = '5x^2 + 3x + 4'
y = '12x^2 + 2x - 6'
z = '2x - 3x^2 + 4'
print(x.split()[0])
print(y.split()[0])
print(z.split('+')[0])
# split default argument is space
```

**Output**

```
5x^2
12x^2
2x - 3x^2
```

And If you want to take only the numbers with the ^ operator without the whole text before, change `z.split('+')[0]` to:

```
print(z.split()[2])
# 3x^2
```